# Divide an image into radial sections and select values in an individual section

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

This is what I would like to do in python: First, give a particular point on the image(shown in red), I would like to section it radially into any given number of equally spaced sections. Then I would like to select pixel intensities in each section one at a time(shown in blue). Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: interesting question, but maybe too many questions at once. maybe you should show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. just to get it right, you have an image, split it into those pieslices, and only show one section at a time (shown in blue). the rest of the image should be more transparent at that moment / not shown at all?

Comment: please review [ask]. "what you tried so far" is **proof of work**. if you don't do that, you just waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than draw your background white and fill in the sector in red or blue, draw instead your background in black and fill your sector with white. Then you can use a multiplication, or bitwise-AND to select the pixels in your real image based on the sector mask.

Now you just need to draw one sector at a time, filled with white. You know the centre, so you just need 2 more points to construct the triangle. As the longest line possible in any image is the diagonal, calculate the length of that. Now, using that as the length of each radial line emanating from the centre, you can use simple trigonometry to calculate the two lines, since you know the angle between them is 360/N where N is the number of sectors. Don't worry that you calculate two vertices outside your image's edges, all libraries will allow you to do that.

Here is some code - not too thoroughly tested - but you get the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

h, w   = 600, 1200   # image height and width
cx, cy = 200, 300    # (x,y) coordinates of circle centre
N      = 16          # number of slices in our pie
l      = h + w       # length of radial lines - larger than necessary

# Create each sector in white on black background
for sector in range(N):
    startAngle = sector * 360/N
    endAngle   = startAngle + 360/N
    x1 = cx + l * math.sin(math.radians(startAngle))
    y1 = cy - l * math.cos(math.radians(startAngle))
    x2 = cx + l * math.sin(math.radians(endAngle))
    y2 = cy - l * math.cos(math.radians(endAngle))
    vertices = [(cy, cx), (y1, x1), (y2, x2)]
    print(f'DEBUG: sector={sector}, startAngle={startAngle}, endAngle={endAngle}')
    # Make empty black canvas
    im = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
    # Draw this pie slice in white
    cv2.fillPoly(im, np.array([vertices],'int32'), 255)
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-{sector:03d}.png', im)
    cv2.imshow('title',im)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

If you start with this image:

[image]

and change the code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

orig = cv2.imread('artistic-swirl.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
print(orig.shape)

h, w   = 600, 1200   # image height and width
cx, cy = 200, 300    # (x,y) coordinates of circle centre
N      = 16          # number of slices in our pie
l      = h + w       # length of radial lines - larger than necessary

# Create each sector in white on black background
for sector in range(N):
    startAngle = sector * 360/N
    endAngle   = startAngle + 360/N
    x1 = cx + l * math.sin(math.radians(startAngle))
    y1 = cy - l * math.cos(math.radians(startAngle))
    x2 = cx + l * math.sin(math.radians(endAngle))
    y2 = cy - l * math.cos(math.radians(endAngle))
    vertices = [(cy, cx), (y1, x1), (y2, x2)]
    print(f'DEBUG: sector={sector}, startAngle={startAngle}, endAngle={endAngle}')
    # Make empty black canvas
    im = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
    # Draw this pie slice in white
    cv2.fillPoly(im, np.array([vertices],'int32'), 255)
    cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-{sector:03d}.png', im)
    #cv2.imshow('title',im)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    mask = np.dstack((im,im,im))
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(mask,orig)
    cv2.imshow('image',res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: You could have used Mr. Paddington :)

Comment: @JeruLuke I am longer allowed to use Mr Paddington  Apparently all images must be CC-BY-SA 4.0 and I cannot take advantage of *"right to use for educational purposes"*.

Comment: Is that a rule now?

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes. My intentions may be purely educational, but StackOverflow itself is commercial. And apparently I warrant that any image I share may be re-used under CC-BY-SA 4.0 by anyone else and I cannot permit other folks to use images that are not mine in ways different from my intended *"educational fair use"*.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the day that they pay us for solving/answering from the ad money. teachers get paid.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It's going to be a long wait - you better get a  or a